# Определение степени узла в идеально сбалансированном дереве

Tags: c++, дерево

Весь вопрос изложен в заголовке. Вариативность степени определить нетрудно - 1 или 2, иных вариантов нет, но как это написать на языке c++? Реализация дерева такая:

```
struct tree {
int inf;
tree*right;
tree*left;
};

tree * node(int x) {
tree*n = new tree;
n->inf;
n->left = n->right = NULL; 
return n; 
}

void create(tree *&tr, int n) { 
int x; 
if (n > 0) {
    cin >> x; 
    tr = node(x); 
    int nl = n / 2; 
    int nr = n - nl - 1; 
    create(tr->left, nl); 
    create(tr->right, nr);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
tr->deg = 0;
if (nl>0)   //ведь это же условие создания детки, верно?
   tr->deg++; 
if (nr>0)
   tr->deg++;
```

Comment: Так, подождите. Моя ошибка - непонятно описана задача. Узел, у которого нужно посчитать степень, вводится с клавиатуры. Куда его послать?

Comment: посчитать для данного числа nl и nr и сделать то же самое

Comment: всё равно не получается